GetCursorPos shows incorrect coordinates if scale in Windows is 125% or more
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    POINT p;
    while (GetCursorPos(&p))
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << p.x << "," << p.y;
        Sleep(100);
    }
}

What should I do so that the coordinates are shown correctly with a scaling of 125%?
My monitor resolution is 2560x1080, but when I run the script and move the cursor to the lower-right corner, it shows 2047,863 in the terminal. If I set the scaling to 100% instead of 125%, it shows correctly(2559,1079).

This is not a script. You may not run it. You can only compile it.

2047 * 1.25 is 2559. 863 * 1.25 is 1079. I don't understand what issue you are talking about.

I assume DPI awareness might have an effect on this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

Does GetPhysicalCursorPos make a difference?
